# Haskell binary tree predicate for genetic sorting

Tags: haskell, tree, heap, binary-tree, predicate

Really new to Haskell and I can't figure this out. How to check if a `Node` in a given binary tree is bigger than its children?

```
module IntTree where

data IntTree = Leaf Int
             | Node Int IntTree IntTree
             deriving (Eq,Show)

t1 :: IntTree
t1 = Node 1999 (Node 1963 (Leaf 1925)
                          (Leaf 1933))
               (Node 1956 (Leaf 1932)
                          (Leaf 1924))


t2 :: IntTree
t2 = Node 1999 (Node 1922 (Leaf 1925)
                          (Leaf 1933))
               (Node 1956 (Leaf 1932)
                          (Leaf 1924))

descendingTree :: Ord a => IntTree -> Bool
```

The function `descendingTree` which will get an `IntTree` and will give me a Boolean in return, signalling whether it is true for every node in the tree that the node's value is bigger than its two children nodes' values; if it has children of course. How can I write this function?

Comment: Did you mean to have `data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)`? Otherwise the `Ord a` constraint on `descendingTree` makes no sense. Anyway, what have you already tried? I'll give you a hint and say that if you check whether a node is greater than all its children, that node's value is the maximum of it and all its children. Therefore, when checking a `Node`, check both subtrees, and then run comparisons between the values at the roots of the subtrees and the current `Node` itself.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One nice and efficient way of sorting a binary tree would possibly be done by the `Zipper` type. I would advise you to have a look at [Zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers)

Comment: How to figure out the syntax to make that work what I said in the first sentence of my question ;D

Comment: @Redu, why would you "sort" a binary tree using a zipper? And what does that have to do with checking if a binary tree is heap-ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: <s>*slowly*</s> *by directly following your data type definition*.

```
descendingTree :: IntTree -> Bool     -- no `a`, so no `Ord a` too
-- data IntTree = Leaf Int
descendingTree   (Leaf i) = leaf i
--              | Node Int IntTree IntTree
descendingTree   (Node  i     lt     rt  ) = node i lt rt
```

In case it's a leaf, there's nothing to check:

```
leaf _ = True
```

In case it's a node, it *always* has two children; this is guaranteed by its type definition. There simply is no other possibility in the type.

```
node i lt rt =
```

Here you need to fill out your test:

```
        i > value lt &&
        i > value rt &&
```

the two checks will be done; if one fails the whole `&&` expression fails and returns `False`. Good. What if the two tests succeed?

```
        every_node_is_greater .... &&
        every_node_is_greater ....
```

Can you fill in the blanks?

Can you write the definition for `every_node_is_greater`? Do you need to?

Of course the two functions `leaf` and `node` are completely redundant; they only served as a mental stepping blocks here, to remove the writing block for us. :) You'd usually write the code right in the corresponding clause in the `descendingTree` definition.

One more definition needs to be written here, for `value`, the new abstraction that we've introduced as we were exploring the problem space (*"what if we had a way to know the "value" of a node? we'll deal with the specifics later..."*). Now it is finally time to flesh it out. Again, simply (and slowly) follow the type, and handle the cases it presents.